# Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority

Tags: android, android-fileprovider, snapchat

I have integrated Snapchat's Creative Kit in my Android app. After processing, I receive an image from the server in the form of Byte Array which I am saving to the disk and then sending the file to the Snapchat's Creative Kit as shown below.

```
 private fun downloadImage(
    fileName: String,
    imageByteArray: ByteArray?): Uri? {
    val state = Environment.getExternalStorageState()

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED == state) {
        val downloadDir = File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context?.getString(R.string.app_name)
        )

        if (!downloadDir.isDirectory) {
            downloadDir.mkdirs()
        }

        val file = File(downloadDir, fileName)
        var ostream: FileOutputStream? = null
        try {
            ostream = FileOutputStream(file)
            ostream.write(imageByteArray)
            ostream.flush()
            ostream.close()
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    val snapCreativeKitApi = SnapCreative.getApi(context!!)
    val snapMediaFactory = SnapCreative.getMediaFactory(context!!)
    lateinit var snapPhotoFile: SnapPhotoFile
    try {
        snapPhotoFile = snapMediaFactory.getSnapPhotoFromFile(file)
    } catch (e: SnapMediaSizeException) {
        return
    }
    val snapPhotoContent = SnapPhotoContent(snapPhotoFile)
    snapCreativeKitApi.send(snapPhotoContent)
    }
}
```

I have also added `provider` in the manifest file as shown below:

```
  <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths_app" />
    </provider>
```

And in the `provider_paths_app.xml`, I have tried all the possible paths by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953476/android-how-to-get-a-content-uri-for-a-file-in-the-external-storage-public-d) answer and none of them works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path
    name="My App Name"
    path="." />
</paths>
```

With the above path, I am getting the below error.

```
Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority my.package.name.fileprovider
```

All I have to do is send this image to Snapchat but I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths >
    <files-path name="myapp" path="images/"/>
</paths>` .Uninstall old one.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Now, getting this error: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/My App Name/image.jpg

Comment: https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage/issues/78

Comment: I was using different manifests on each of my build types folders (develop, staging and release) just so I could set different authorities on my providers. Using the ${applicationId} variable allowed me to unify my manifest files into a single one again. Nice :)

Answer (score 223, accepted):

First, write the following tag in manifest under the `<application>` tag

```
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

Then create a xml folder in `res` and create a file named: provider_paths.xml
and then copy paste the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

And now here's where most developers make mistakes: in your script,  create your File with:

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(Objects.requireNonNull(getApplicationContext()),
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
```

Comment: Thank you for this.. I tried all other solutions but `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider"` is what made it finally work for me.

Comment: For me, the issue was case sensitivity. I hade `.FileProvider` in one place and `.fileprovider` in the other. The case must match!

Comment: I tried to BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider" is what made it finally work for me

Comment: why is it complicated like hell

Comment: @Aadam yes I am wondering them deprecate us to use 2 rows but now we have 40 extra lines and it still need something more.

Comment: Why am I getting this error ?? 'BuildConfig' is inaccessible due to it's protection level

Answer (score 31):

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

This is my provider declaration, the value of ${applicationId} is "com.limxtop.research", make sure that the name of authorities is the same with that of the codes below.

```
            // Create the file where the photo should save.
            File file = null;
            try {
                file = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
            // The second parameter is the name of authorities.
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.limxtop.research.fileprovider", file);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivityForResult(intent, fullSizeRequestCode);
```

So, maybe your codes post here is not complete, there you should pass "my.package.name.fileprovider" as parameter some where.

Answer (score 15):

In my case.

I have a library project .Let's call it :LibApk

When I code this : applicationId "my.package.name" in the build.grale(app)

when build gradle  tell me that : ***Library projects cannot set applicationId.***

***applicationId is set to 'com.darcy.apkupdate' in default config.***

So ,I delete applicationId "my.package.name" .

Then ,build.gradle look like this :
[image]

But I forgot update the AndroidManifest.xml file which use ***${applicationId}***

[image]

This is the problem!!!

So I changed the variable to constant .The result looks like below picture:
[image]

After This ,It's wokr for me!

Hope this is help you...

Answer (score 10):

If the build's suffix is different, it makes sense to make a change like this.

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext.get(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", file)
```

Comment: changing from .provider to  .fileprovider fixed my issue. Thanks @ulaserdegor

Answer (score 9):

The problem here is, you use the class name **.provider** for authorities in manifest
and use **.fileprovider** class name in java code.

```
 <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths_app" />
    </provider>



Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority my.package.name.fileprovider
```

Just rename fileprovider to **provider**

Answer (score 8):

In My Case;

Manifest File:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Code:

```
import androidx.multidex.BuildConfig // NOT DO THIS!!!

val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+ ".provider", _tempFile)
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority androidx.multidex.provider
```

**Do not use androidx.multidex.BuildConfig, Because this values are not the values of our application:**

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package androidx.multidex;

public final class BuildConfig {
    public static final boolean DEBUG = false;
    public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "androidx.multidex";
    public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "release";
    public static final String FLAVOR = "";
    public static final int VERSION_CODE = -1;
    public static final String VERSION_NAME = "";

    public BuildConfig() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It works for me, for more clarification,
I Import :
import androidx.multidex.BuildConfig

instead of:
import com.myapplication.packagename.BuildConfig;

Comment: yeap, autoimport is evil sometimes, faced this same problem, sadly found solution after resolving by my own -_-

Answer (score 3):

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "{yourPAckageName}.fileprovider",
                                file);
```

**to**

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(Objects.requireNonNull(getApplicationContext()),
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
```

I spent a day finding a solution. This part is very important. That saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

`{applicationId}` == `com.companyName.application`
append ".provider"

which will be == `com.example.test.provider`

in xml `authorities:com.example.test.provider`

in activity  `Uri mPath = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.example.provider", imageFile);`

Answer (score 1):

### This is Because of this authority name difference

```
   <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
            />
    </provider>

 here Look     
      
      <pre>android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" </pre>
```

Here the authority name is you **packagename.provider**
***(com.example.app.provider)***

```
        val uri: Uri? = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        this.contexts,
        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
        file
    )
```

whenever we copy paste the code the authority may be change from one source to another. in stackoverflow some devs put in manifest **${applicationId}.provider"**  and in uri they put (.fileprovider)  **FileProvider.getUriForFile(
this.contexts,
BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider",
file
)** this is the problem now authority is different that is showing in log

Answer (score 0):

*mImageFromCamera = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".**fileprovider**", mImageFile);
android:authorities="${applicationId}.**fileprovider**"*

authorities must be same in xml and in code

Answer (score 0):

First you use

`File(getExternalFilesDir(null),context?.getString(R.string.app_name));`

---

instead of

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context?.getString(R.string.app_name) // this is deprecated in API29`

---

then use this

`Uri contentUri = getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.mydomain.fileprovider", newFile);`

For more help: [File Provider Description](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider#ProviderDefinition)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `BuildConfig` import class file name:

```
import androidx.multidex.BuildConfig;
```

with:

```
import com.yourAppName.BuildConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

what solved my problem is :

replace your paths app file by this :
take a look at files root, i determined the path with my app package name, change the pkg name to yours.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="files_root"
        path="Android/data/com.my.newproject4" />
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

and also in your provider
use your package name instead of ${applicationId}

same as me here

```
<provider
android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
android:authorities="com.my.newproject4.provider"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">

<meta-data
android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

this is what worked with me
the only solution and way after long time of trying and searching
just this was the problem

maybe it helps someone
i hope for you a good luck

Answer (score 0):

I had recently converted my app module into a library module where it **`applicationId`** had to be removed from my `build.gradle` file (of the module which I converted from an app module to a library module).

Below is the provider tag of `AndroidManifest` file in converted library module

```
   <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"
            tools:replace="android:resource" />
    </provider>
```

Now, the new app module where I am using the library has different **`applicationId`** in it's `AndroidManifest`. So, we need to pass the new `applicationId` wherever we use `FileProvider` authority is needed in code.

Or `android:authorities` in library `AndroidManifest` needs to be changed to make it exactly same as to `FileProvider` authority used in our code.

Example Usage:

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, Constants.ExternalFileProviderAuthority, f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the following tag in the manifest under the `<application>` tag:

```
<provider
   android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
   android:authorities="${applicationId}.imagepickerprovider"
   android:exported="false"
   android:grantUriPermissions="true">
   <meta-data
       android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
       android:resource="@xml/imagepicker_provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Then create an XML folder in res and create a file named `imagepicker_provider_paths.xml` and then copy paste the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <cache-path name="cacheDir" path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

To (fix Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority) that appears when you need to open the camera from web view in Flutter for android.

First, write in manifest inside the  tag

```
   <provider
       android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
       android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
       android:exported="false"
       android:grantUriPermissions="true">
       <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
           android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
   </provider>
```

Then create an xml folder in res and create a file provider_paths.xml and then copy paste the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

Answer (score -1):

Its fileprovider and not provider

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
```

Answer (score -2):

Change the authorities to a unique name to solve the issue like

`android:authorities="${applicationId}.myUniquefileprovider"`

also in java code

Answer (score -2):

I just removed the '$' from android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" and it works like a charm now.