# resource xml/provider_paths (aka com.BQProject.betterquestx:xml/provider_paths) not found

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-manifest

Sorry, I have some problems in my Xamarin Forms aplication, I am trying to trigger the installation of the application using this code:

```
public void LetsInstall(string filepath)
    {
        Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(filepath);
        Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
        Android.Net.Uri path = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, context.PackageName + ".provider", file);
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N)
        {
            Android.Net.Uri URIAPK = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(context, context.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".provider", (Java.IO.File)filepath);
            Intent intS = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            intS.SetData(URIAPK);
            intS.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intS);
        }
        else
        {
            Android.Net.Uri URIAPK = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile((Java.IO.File)filepath);
            Intent intS = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
            intS.SetDataAndType(URIAPK, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            intS.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intS);
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work out for me. A `Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.BQproject.betterquestx.provider'` error occurs on line 5

I tried to register this code in AndroidManifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.BQProject.betterquestx" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="29" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <application android:label="BetterQuestX.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:icon="@drawable/icon_about">
         <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

I also created Resources/xml/provider_paths and added code to it:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

As a result, the `resource xml/provider_paths (aka com.BQProject.betterquestx:xml/provider_paths) not found. This error is likely caused by an issue with the AndroidManifest.xml file or an Android manifest generation attribute in a source code file` error appeared and I do not know what to do with it, please help

Comment: Have you check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56598480/couldnt-find-meta-data-for-provider-with-authority

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it didn't lead to anything

Comment: try the solution under this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624953/how-to-fix-an-authority-error-in-android-studio