# My app quits as soon as picture is selected

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have created an app that basically takes a picture and saves it to the gallery. The only problem is that after the picture is taken it takes you to the screen where you can preview it with the two buttons that say okay and cancel. Once you click okay, the app quits. The image is still saved to the gallery but I want the app to stay open. I also want the app to display a bitmap of the image on an imageView that I have.

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    <- Line 22

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();    <- Line 34
            }
        });
    }

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                // I AM UNSURE WHAT CODE TO PUT HERE. DOES ANYONE KNOW WHAT I SHOULD BE PUTTING HERE?
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                //This is where the error is occurring but I do not know why.
Line 56 ->      Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.app", photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }

    String currentPhotoPath;

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;

    }

    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
}
```

Here is my error message

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.app, PID: 22357
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.example.app
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:606)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:579)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
    --> at com.example.app.MainActivity.dispatchTakePictureIntent(MainActivity.java:56)
    --> at com.example.app.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:22)
    --> at com.example.app.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14966)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29315)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7777)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 22357 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not crashing?  Include any relevant logs.

Comment: It will crash because of wrong code in onActivityResult. The logcat will tell you.

Comment: I updated my code because I changed it a little while after posting the question. I have also included the error message. I have made edits within both the MainActivity.java file and the stack trace to point to where the errors are.

Comment: seems like this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56598480/couldnt-find-meta-data-for-provider-with-authority

Comment: Show paths xml file and provider definition in manifest.