# i Couldn't find meta-data for provider

Tags: flutter, class, metadata, androidx, provider

how are you sure
i have issue at this code that you tell me
([Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56598480/couldnt-find-meta-data-for-provider-with-authority)
)
i issue is this code

`FileProvider.getUriForFile(Objects.requireNonNull(getApplicationContext()), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);`

i want help me
this code where's should put on???
i don't understand
please help me