# Error: Unable to create photo on disk on Android - Ionic using Capacitor Camera Plugin

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-camera, capacitor, ionic7

I am trying to use the Capacitor Camera Plugin in Ionic (v7) for an Android App (have not tested in iOS, but no issue on Web). This is the code to get the image:

```
const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
  quality: 100,
  allowEditing: true,
  resultType: CameraResultType.DataUrl,
  source: CameraSource.Camera,
  saveToGallery: false,

});
```

when I try to run the Camera, I get this error message:

`Error: Unable to create photo on disk`

I have this setup in my AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_MEDIA" />

<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.zxing.client.android" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true"/>
```

Any help will be extremely welcome.

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue? I am facing the same

Comment: Hi, i ended up using this parameters: quality: 100, resultType: CameraResultType.DataUrl, source: CameraSource.Camera, saveToGallery: false, correctOrientation: true. I dont know if correct orientation fixed it. But it is working now

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `FileProvider`. Images have to be saved to device, even if `saveToGallery` is set to false. You just can't access them from gallery.

The complete error message from Android Studio is:

```
Unable to create photo on disk
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority my.example.app.fileprovider at 
androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getFileProviderPathsMetaData(FileProvider.java:664) at 
androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:695) at 
androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:645) at 
androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:449)
```

For info on how to add `FileProvider` checkout this post:
[Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56598480/couldnt-find-meta-data-for-provider-with-authority)

Answer (score 0):

To enable file provider using Capacitor Camera, check if this block of code (inside < application > tag) has on AndroidManifest.xml, for some reason it was just removed acditenly on my code.

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```